# How to match a string with exactly one digit in R Studio?

Tags: r, digits

I am trying to match a string with exactly one digit in R Studio
I already this Code:

grep("[:0-9:]+\d{0,1}]" , text_strings, value = TRUE)

but the output is still wrong

Comment: Some examples of expected input and output would help a lot here!

Comment: I'll leave it to you to translate but: start of string, 0 or more non digits, one digit, zero or more non digits, end of string. It's not too bad to figure out the patterns for each of those in regex.

Comment: "','is a separator, so please extract these numbers 125,789,1450
and also these 564,90456", "We like to to offer you 7890$ per
month in order to complete this task... we are joking", "You are
going to learn 3 things, the first one is not to extract, and
2 and 3 are simply digits.", "Have fun with our mighty test, you
are going to support science, progress, mankind wellness and you

So this is the text and I need to filter the rows with exactly one digit (e.g.. 2 and 3 in the 
penultimate sentence)

Comment: thank you for your help! actually I trying to extract one single digit in each sentence, e.g. 
"We like to to offer you 7890$ per month in order to complete this task... we are joking", "You are going to learn 3 things, the first one is not to extract, and 2 and 3 are simply digits.", "Have fun with our mighty test, you are going to support science, progress, mankind wellness and you So this is the text and I need to filter the rows with exactly one digit 

so the output here has to be 3, 2 and 3 (which means 1 digit) without something like 125,789,1450 , bc there is more than one digit

Answer (score 1):

Since `grep()` and `grepl()` don't use extended regular expressions, I would try something with the **stringr** package, as follows:

```
text_strings = c("','is a separator, so please extract these numbers 125,789,1450 and also these 564,90456",
                 "We like to to offer you 7890$ per month in order to complete this task... we are joking",
                 "You are going to learn 3 things, the first one is not to extract, and 2 and 3 are simply digits.",
                 "Have fun with our mighty test, you are going to support science, progress, mankind wellness and you")
stringr::str_extract_all(text_strings, '(?<!\\d)\\d(?!\\d)')
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "3" "2" "3"

[[4]]
character(0)
```